# How to change opacity of image in Android Gallery

Tags: android, image, gallery

I had made a gallery view with images over a background image and I noticed that they seemed transparent. I was wondering if there is a way to make then 100% opaque in the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gallery class has a method setUnselectAlpha(float alpha). Have fun with that.

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html#setUnselectedAlpha%28float%29)

Comment: Thank you, But I am new to java but experienced in XML, Is there a way to do it in the XML?

Comment: inside the gallery's opening tag, android:unselectedAlpha="1.0". FYI there's not much you can do with just XML so you might as well start working on java.